# Bad compile errors for a setup wizard-Cannot find symbol

Tags: java, arrays, string, compiler-errors, jframe

I am making a setup wizard for a tax application and I get errors that I don't know how to solve. Please help!
My Error is:

```
Setup.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
                Colors = new String[]{"black", "blue", "cyan", "darkGray", "gray", "green", "lightGray", "magenta", "orange", "pink", "red", "white", "yellow"};
                ^
  symbol:   variable Colors
  location: class Setup
Setup.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
                final JList colors = new JList(Colors);
                                               ^
  symbol:   variable Colors
  location: class Setup
Setup.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
                        Colors = new String[]{"black", "blue", "cyan", "darkGray", "gray", "green", "lightGray", "magenta", "orange", "pink", "red", "white", "yellow"};
                        ^
  symbol: variable Colors
Setup.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
```

If anybody knows the answer, and uses StackOverflow, please ask them to awnser this question!
Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
public class Setup {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static String colorSelected;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame f = new JFrame("Test Setup wizard");
        Container a = f.getContentPane();
        a.setBackground(Color.white);
        a.setLayout(new  FlowLayout());
        JLabel question1 = new JLabel("What would you like the background color to be?");
        JButton Next = new JButton("Next");
        Colors = new String[]{"black", "blue", "cyan", "darkGray", "gray", "green", "lightGray", "magenta", "orange", "pink", "red", "white", "yellow"};
        final JList colors = new JList(Colors);
        colors.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        colors.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
        JScrollPane listScroller = new JScrollPane(colors);
        colors.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
                public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                    int index = e.getFirstIndex();
                    Colors = new String[]{"black", "blue", "cyan", "darkGray", "gray", "green", "lightGray", "magenta", "orange", "pink", "red", "white", "yellow"};
                    String colorSelected = Colors[index];
                    }
                });
        f.add(question1);
        f.add(listScroller);
        f.add(Next);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(500,500);
        f.setVisible(true);
        final ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("HardDisk.jpg");
        f.setIconImage(img.getImage());
        Next.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent Ev) {
                    final Color[] Selected = new Color[1];
                    if (colorSelected .equals("black")) {
                        Selected[0] = new Color(0,0,0);
                    }
                    else if (colorSelected .equals("blue")) {
                        Selected[0] = new Color(0,0,255);
                    }
                    else if (colorSelected .equals("cyan")) {
                        Selected[0] = new Color(0,225,225);
                    }
                    else if (colorSelected .equals("darkGray")) {
                        Selected[0] = new Color(169,169,169);
                    }
                    else if (colorSelected .equals("gray")) {
                        Selected[0] = new Color(128,128,128);
                    }
                    else if (colorSelected .equals("green")) {
                        Selected[0] = new Color(0,255,0);
                    }
                    else if (colorSelected .equals("lightGray")) {
                        Selected[0] = new Color(211,211,211);
                    }
                    else if (colorSelected .equals("magenta")) {
                        Selected[0] = new Color(255,0,255);
                    }
                    else if (colorSelected .equals("orange")) {
                        Selected[0] = new Color(255,165,0);
                    }
                    else if (colorSelected .equals("pink")) {
                        Selected[0] = new Color(255,20,147);
                    }
                    else if (colorSelected .equals("red")) {
                        Selected[0] = new Color(255,0,0);
                    }
                    else if (colorSelected .equals("white")) {
                        Selected[0] = new Color(255,255,255);
                    }
                    else if (colorSelected .equals("yellow")) {
                        Selected[0] = new Color(255,255,0);
                    }
                f.dispose();
                JLabel complete = new JLabel("You are now complete.");
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Complete");
                Container a = f.getContentPane();
                a.setBackground(Selected[0]);
                f.add(complete);
                f.setSize(500,500);
                f.setVisible(true);
                f.setIconImage(img.getImage());
            }
            });
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!
P.S: Only solve the first error!!! That fixes the others too!!!

Comment: *"Thanks,

                              PrivateName"*  Don't include sigs. in questions, they are noise.

Answer (score 5):

try leaving off the size of the array in the declaration and using curly braces instead of square braces. Such as:

```
Colors = new String[]{"black", "blue", "cyan", "darkGray", "gray", "green", "lightGray", "magenta", "orange", "pink", "red", "white", "yellow"};
```

Comment: It still doesn't compile but what the compiler gives me is weird. It is: 'Note: Setup.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: that means that something in that class is causing a compiler warning to be thrown. Usually a good IDE will be able to catch those and tell you what they are. For now, you might try adding @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") to the top of your class declaration.

Comment: It does compile, but it just says that _while_ it's compiling.

Answer (score 3):

This line is incorrect must be wrapped with `{}` instead of `[]`

```
new String[12]["black", "blue", "cyan", "darkGray", "gray", "green", "lightGray", "magenta", "orange", "pink", "red", "white", "yellow"];
```

Should be

```
new String[]{"black", "blue", "cyan", "darkGray", "gray", "green", "lightGray", "magenta", "orange", "pink", "red", "white", "yellow"};
```

And you have to add the JSrollPane to the frame instead of your JList.

```
JScrollPane listScroller = new JScrollPane(colors);
f.add(listScroller);
```

And also you have to add the `JLabel` to the contentPane of the JFrame

```
JLabel question1 = new JLabel("What would you like the background color to be?");
f.add(question1);
```

As @MadProgrammer always suggest i prefer adding to a container as a JPanel instead of JFrame.

Comment: @PrivateName don't understand xD consider accepting an answer

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are not initialised using square brackets, they are [initialised with curly brackets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html), so;

```
Colors = new String[]{"black", "blue", "cyan", "darkGray", "gray", "green", "lightGray", "magenta", "orange", "pink", "red", "white", "yellow"};
```

Answer (score 1):

Array initializers use `{}` instead of `[]` (for the literal part), and you don't declare the size of the array, as:

```
Colors = new String[] {"black", "blue", "cyan", "darkGray", 
                         "gray",  "green", "lightGray", "magenta", 
                         "orange", "pink", "red", "white", "yellow"};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new String[12]["black", ...]
```

should be

```
new String[]{"black", ...}
```

or even just

```
{"black", ...}  // no "new String[]"
```

You don't need to specify the size; it would be redundant as it's simply the number of elements you've declared.

Answer (score 1):

```
new String[12] here is of Array is 12 but there are 13 elements in your array.
```

also no need that

```
 Colors = new String[12]{"black", "blue", "cyan", "darkGray", "gray", "green", "lightGray", "magenta", "orange", "pink", "red", "white", "yellow"};
```

Just use

```
 Colors = new String[]{"black", "blue", "cyan", "darkGray", "gray", "green", "lightGray", "magenta", "orange", "pink", "red", "white", "yellow"};
```

Comment: This is true, its also not the problem, the 12 shouldn't be there, 13 or otherwise

Comment: yas :) that's the problem here