# RGB creating with not a statement error

Tags: java, arrays, swing, compiler-errors, rgb

I have 39 errors but the are all the same error on the same thing (kindve) and I don't know what's wrong! The errors are all similar to this one:

```
Setup.java:31: error: ')' expected
                                                Selected[0] = (0,0,0);
                                                                ^
Setup.java:31: error: not a statement
                                                Selected[0] = (0,0,0);
                                                                 ^
Setup.java:31: error: ';' expected
                                                Selected[0] = (0,0,0);
                                                                  ^
```

This is really confusing and I don't know whats wrong Please help!
Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.color.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Setup {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test Setup wizard");
        Container a = f.getContentPane();
        a.setBackground(Color.white);
        a.setLayout(new  FlowLayout());
        JLabel question1 = new JLabel("What would you like the background color to be?");
        JButton Next = new JButton("Next");
        String Colors[];
        Colors = new String[]{"black", "blue", "cyan", "darkGray", "gray", "green", "lightGray", "magenta", "orange", "pink", "red", "white", "yellow"};
        JList colors = new JList(Colors);
        colors.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        colors.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
        JScrollPane listScroller = new JScrollPane(colors);
        f.add(question1);
        f.add(colors);
        f.add(Next);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(500,500);
        f.setVisible(true);
        final ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(HardDisk.jpg);
        f.setIconImage(img.getImage());
        Next.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent Ev) {
                    final String selected = colors.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    final Color[] Selected = new Color[1];
                    if (selected == "black") {
                        Selected[0] = (0,0,0);
                    }
                    else if (selected == "blue") {
                        Selected[0] = (0,0,255);
                    }
                    else if (selected == "cyan") {
                        Selected[0] = (0,225,225);
                    }
                    else if (selected == "darkGray") {
                        Selected[0] = (169,169,169);
                    }
                    else if (selected == "gray") {
                        Selected[0] = (128,128,128);
                    }
                    else if (selected == "green") {
                        Selected[0] = (0,255,0);
                    }
                    else if (selected == "lightGray") {
                        Selected[0] = (211,211,211);
                    }
                    else if (selected == "magenta") {
                        Selected[0] = (255,0,255);
                    }
                    else if (selected == "orange") {
                        Selected[0] = (255,165,0);
                    }
                    else if (selected == "pink") {
                        Selected[0] = (255,20,147)
                    }
                    else if (selected == "red") {
                        Selected[0] = (255,0,0);
                    }
                    else if (selected == "white") {
                        Selected[0] = (255,255,255);
                    }
                    else if (selected == "yellow") {
                        Selected[0] = (255,255,0);
                    }
                f.dispose();
                JLabel complete = new JLabel("You are now complete.");
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Complete");
                Container a = f.getContentPane();
                a.setBackground(Selected[0]);
                f.add(complete);
                f.setSize(500,500);
                f.setVisible(true);
                f.setIconImage(img.getImage());
            }
            });
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated!
Thanks!

**ATTENTION:
THIS POST HAS BEEN MOVED TO:**
[HERE.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17532928/bad-compile-errors-for-a-setup-wizard)
*Thank you for your cooperation*

Comment: `final Color[] Selected = new Color[1];` Is there a reason you create an array with only one object in it?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you wanted something like:

```
Selected[0] = new Color(0,0,0);
```

But you should also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java), as you're currently comparing string references using `==`. To be honest, you'd be better off populating a `Map<String, Color>` rather than using all of those `if` statements.

There's also no obvious reason why you're using an array instead of just a simple variable of type `Color`.

Comment: I'm using an array or else you get a compile error like: `variable accessed from inner class, must be declared final`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `(0, 0, 0)` by itself isn't a statement.

I think you meant to create a new `Color` object, e.g.

```
Selected[0] = new Color(0, 0, 0);
```

Additionally, don't compare `String` values with the `==` operator, which compares object references to determine if they are the same object.  Use the `equals` method in `String` to compare `String` values.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the Color class to call the constructor using RGB values:

replace this

```
Selected[0] = (0,0,0);
```

with

```
Selected[0] = new Color(0,0,0);
```